# Why will my electron.js app not open when I try npm start even though my code is right?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I need help with my simple hello world program based for `electron.js`.

I was reading the [*quick guide* documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start) on the official `electronjs.org` website.

Esentially I did everything it told me to do on that page including the `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, `index.html` and `main.js`; and installing `electron.js` however when I tried to boot up my program in cmd using `npm start`, I just got 2 messages instead of the program opening.

From there it shows me the cmd command line again waiting for an input which is shown in the picture [image: error]

I don't know what's wrong and no matter how much I try to edit the `package.json` and the `main.js` it still seems to spit out the same error. I was getting so desperate that I just copy and pasted the exact same code in the docs and just edited the author and description as asked in the quick guide.

I am well and truly stuck if anyone has any ideas on how to fix this please let me know, I've also tried some simple troubleshooting, the simple reinstall of the electronjs API, tried administrator cmd, read the forums etc and I can't find anything code will be below..

**main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-first-electron",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.814.0",
    "electron": "^11.1.0",
    "electron.js": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: As your code works (I just copied an tried), it has something to do with your setup. Have you installed npm on your machine, and does it work?

Comment: @Torf Yes my node and npm services do work, in the quick guide it even said to make sure that we had npm and node installed with npm -v and node -v and I have node version v14.15.0 and NPM version 6.14.8, It's really confusing as everything seems to be correct, I turned off my anti virus to double check it ain't just something stupid and simple like that, It could have to do with my OS but it's windows 10 (64 bit) so it's nothing out of support and out of date.